# Cross communication between war and osgi bundle in camel + fuse

Tags: java, apache-camel, osgi, war, jbossfuse

How to communicate with war to bundle using direct-vm? I have created a war file in which I have defined camel routes with unique camelContext. From this war I tried to connect with other bundle B which is purely OSGI bundle with unique camelcontext.

When I tried to do direct-vm:route-abc from war, it is giving me error that there are consumer with direct-vm:route-abc.

Surprisingly I'm not able to see the war's camelContext when I do camel:context-list on karaf console. It lists only osgi bundle context.

Can someone help here?

Thanks in advance.

Ashish

Answer (score 0):

If you use a plain war file then camel does not assume it is running in OSGi. So the camel context is not announced as a service.

You can instead use a plain bundle with blueprint and the camel servlet component to expose camel routes on the web.

Comment: Actually my requirement is like that only. I can't update war to OSGi. Does it mean that if we deploy war using osgi:install war:mvn:~~ it will not register my camelContext as a service?

If that is the case than how this intercommunication happens between war and other OSGi bundle.

Comment: A war is not really an OSGi artifact. So it is deployed kind of standalone in the container. I dont think you can leverage OSGi mechanics to communicate with a plain war.